# How to find parent in a json array if i select child inside child

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to find parent object with complete info like all the child it contains if i select any one child from them from a selector tag with value id.

Here is my html code:

```
<select class="form-control show-tick" id="service_category" data-live-search="true" formControlName="service_category" (change)="selectCategory()">
                                    <option selected="" value="">Select</option>
                                    <ng-template #recursiveList let-categories>
                                        <ng-container *ngFor="let category of categories">
                                            <option [ngValue]="category.id">
                                                <i *repeatTimes="category.depth" class="material-icons">remove</i>
                                                <span *ngIf="category.parent != null">{{ category.name }}</span>
                                                <b *ngIf="category.parent == null">{{ category.name }}</b>
                                            </option>
                                            <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: category.children}"></ng-container>
                                        </ng-container>
                                    </ng-template>
                                    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: categories}"></ng-container>
                                </select>
```

And here is my json array:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Travel",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Car",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Cab Booking",
                    "parent": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]
```

I want that if i select cab booking from select option then, it i can get whole array object with its parent and all childs.

Comment: Somewhere in your code you are reading and parsing the JSON string to a JavaScript object. In this step you could replace the parent id with an actual reference to the parent. You could use the object as value `[ngValue]="category"`. Then you can access the grandparent with `category.parent.parent` and grandchildren with `category.children[2].children[0]`. You could even access siblings with `category.parent.children[2]`

Comment: How can i access category.parent.parent, when category.parent=someid, not any further oject name parent.

Comment: Please read my whole comment, not only parts of it: _"
Somewhere in your code you are reading and parsing the JSON string to a JavaScript object. In this step you could replace the parent id with an actual reference to the parent."_

Comment: How can i do so. Can you do it please.

Comment: Here is an example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yvqezj?file=src/app/app.component.ts). In the example the references are set manually. You should do this automatically but you can find many questions about this topic (searching and changing nested objects) on Stackoverflow.

Comment: I didn't get with that static code. Please provide the fully dynamic code according to my data and when i select nested child in level 3 i can get full object of that with its top level parent.

Comment: Can you try it yourself first, show your approach and ask a specific programming question about what you are struggling with? Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service. I already gave you a working basic example. This is a more generic approach [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yvqezj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: If this example is helpful for you you should fork it because I usually delete my example projects after 1-2 days.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse the JSON data to JavaScript data. After you parsed the data you can postprocess the data and replace all parent IDs with references to the parent. Then you could use the whole `category` object as `[ngValue]` instead of just the `id`. After these changes you can traverse the complete tree in both directions with expressions like:

```
category.parent.parent
category.children[2].children[0]
category.parent.children[2]
```

This is an minimal example for an array of 2-level nested objects like in your question:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

const json = `[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Travel1",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Car",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "Cab Booking",
                    "parent": 2
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Bike",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 5,
                    "name": "Bike Booking",
                    "parent": 4
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    "id": 11,
    "name": "Travel2",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 12,
            "name": "Car",
            "parent": 11,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 13,
                    "name": "Cab Booking",
                    "parent": 12
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 14,
            "name": "Bike",
            "parent": 11,
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": 15,
                    "name": "Bike Booking",
                    "parent": 14
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
]`;

interface Obj {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  parent: Obj | null;
  children?: Obj[];
}

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="objs">
      <select [(ngModel)]="value">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let obj of objs">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let child of obj.children">
            <option *ngFor="let el of child.children" [ngValue]="el">
              {{ el.id }}
            </option>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
      </select>
      <p *ngIf="value">Children: {{ value.children }}</p>
      <p *ngIf="value">Parent: {{ value.parent.name }}</p>
      <p *ngIf="value">
        Parent's first child: {{ value.parent.children[0].name }}
      </p>
      <p *ngIf="value">Grandparent: {{ value.parent.parent.name }}</p>
      <p *ngIf="value">
        Grandparent's first child: {{ value.parent.parent.children[0].name }}
      </p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  objs: Obj[] | null = null;
  value: Obj | null = null;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.objs = JSON.parse(json).map(obj => {
      obj.children.forEach(child => {
        child.parent = obj;
        child.children.forEach(grandchild => (grandchild.parent = child));
      });
      return obj;
    });
  }
}
```

The selected category is stored in the variable `value` and it's possible to traverse up the tree and back down however you want. This minimal example is limited to the given structure (array of 2-level nested objects).

Here is live demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yvqezj?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Ok thanks! no problem i have done it myself for unlimited level.